# Pivot csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data format in a csv file:

```
1,01,ABC,This is abc101,This is another abc101
1,01,DEF,This is def101,This is another def101
1,02,ABC,This is abc102,This is another abc102
1,02,DEF,This is def102,This is another def102
1,02,GHI,This is ghi102,This is another ghi102
2,01,ABC,This is abc201,This is another abc201
2,01,DEF,This is def201,This is another def201
2,01,GHI,This is ghi201,This is another ghi201
2,03,GHI,This is ghi203,This is another ghi203
3,02,ABC,This is abc302,This is another abc302
3,02,ABC,This is abc302,This is another abc302
3,02,ABC,This is abc302,This is another abc302
4,01,ABC,This is abc401,This is another abc401
4,01,DEF,This is def401,This is another def401
4,01,ABC,This is abc401,This is another abc401
4,02,DEF,This is def402,This is another def402
4,02,DEF,This is def402,This is another def402
```

also I have a variable list = `['ABC','ABC_2','GHI','GHI_2']`
the csv file header list = `['ID1','ID2','Var_name','var_value1','var_value2']`

I need to pivot the above data like the below format
    `[['ID1','ID2','ABC','ABC_2','GHI','GHI_2'], [1,01,'This is abc101','This is another abc101','',''], [1,02,'This is abc102','This is another abc102','This is ghi102','This is another ghi102']]` ..like that

If the variable list = `['GHI','GHI_2','ABC','ABC_2']`
The output will be:
`[['ID1','ID2','GHI','GHI_2','ABC','ABC_2'], [1,01,'','','This is abc101','This is another abc101'], [1,02,'This is ghi102','This is another ghi102','This is abc102','This is another abc102']]` ..like that

That means the list should:

- populate the data for all the IDs
- create null string for those variables which are not present in the above dataset.
- The csv file has no header we have a seperate header list
- populate the nested list, maintaining the same order as the Header list
- populate only those header value i.e. the header list only has values 'ABC','GHI' so the nested list should only populate the values 'ABC' and 'GHI', and should ignore 'DEF' rows from the above dataset.
- For var_value2 it will populate under _2 position like 'This is another abc101' will be under 'ABC_2'

I want to do this in Python 2.7, possibly using Pandas.

```
variable_list = ['ABC','DEF']
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile,delimiter='#',engine='python',header=None)
df.columns = ['ID1','ID2','var_name','var_value']
f=df.set_index(['ID1','ID2','var_name'])['var_value'].unstack(fill_value='').fillna('')[variable_list].reset_index()
L1 = [f.columns.tolist()] + f.values.tolist()
```

This code I have tried for single var_value, now I have two (var_value1, var_value2)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you attempted to use pandas?

Comment: Yes I have used panda but here I have multiple index(ID1 & ID2) and multiple values (var_value1 & var_value2). So facing difficulty

Comment: Could you post your attempt in the question?

Comment: `variable_list = ['ABC','DEF']`
`df = pd.read_csv(csvfile,delimiter='#',engine='python',header=None)`
`df.columns = ['ID1','ID2','var_name','var_value']`
`f=df.set_index(['ID1','ID2','var_name'])['var_value'].unstack(fill_value='').fillna('')[variable_list].reset_index()`
`L1 = [f.columns.tolist()] + f.values.tolist()`

Comment: If you click edit under your question you can put the code there, properly formatted.

Comment: This i have tried when only one var_value was there now I have two var_value (var_value1 & var_value2)

Comment: @FHTMitchell Now please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working:

```
#remove duplicates sample data
print (df)
    0   1    2               3                       4
0   1  01  ABC  This is abc101  This is another abc101
1   1  01  DEF  This is def101  This is another def101
2   1  02  ABC  This is abc102  This is another abc102
3   1  02  DEF  This is def102  This is another def102
4   1  02  GHI  This is ghi102  This is another ghi102
5   2  01  ABC  This is abc201  This is another abc201
6   2  01  DEF  This is def201  This is another def201
7   2  01  GHI  This is ghi201  This is another ghi201
8   2  03  GHI  This is ghi203  This is another ghi203
9   3  02  ABC  This is abc302  This is another abc302
10  4  01  ABC  This is abc401  This is another abc401
11  4  02  DEF  This is def402  This is another def402
```

---

```
#change headers to empty string and 2 for 'ABC','ABC_2','GHI','GHI_2'
df.columns = ['ID1','ID2','Var_name','','2']

#unstack all columns
df = df.set_index(['ID1','ID2', 'Var_name']).unstack()

#excepted columns names for ordering
variable_list = ['ABC','ABC_2', 'GHI', 'GHI_2']

#filter second level of MultiIndex
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1).isin(variable_list)]
#flatten columns names
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(j, i).strip('_') for i, j in df.columns]
df = df.reindex(columns=variable_list).fillna('').reset_index()
print (df)
   ID1 ID2             ABC                   ABC_2             GHI  \
0    1  01  This is abc101  This is another abc101                   
1    1  02  This is abc102  This is another abc102  This is ghi102   
2    2  01  This is abc201  This is another abc201  This is ghi201   
3    2  03                                          This is ghi203   
4    3  02  This is abc302  This is another abc302                   
5    4  01  This is abc401  This is another abc401                   
6    4  02                                                           

                    GHI_2  
0                          
1  This is another ghi102  
2  This is another ghi201  
3  This is another ghi203  
4                          
5                          
6
```

---

```
#convert to lists
L1 = [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
print (L1[:3])
[['ID1', 'ID2', 'ABC', 'ABC_2', 'GHI', 'GHI_2'], 
 [1, '01', 'This is abc101', 'This is another abc101', '', ''], 
 [1, '02', 'This is abc102', 'This is another abc102', 'This is ghi102', 'This is another ghi102']]
```

Comment: it is working but i have a pre populated list ['ABC','ABC_2','GHI','GHI_2'] and I want my output in the same order , your solution is in order ['ABC', 'GHI', 'ABC_2', 'GHI_2'] -> which you have manipulated here, but it should be in the same order of the prepopulated list.

Comment: @SourajitRoyChowdhury - You are right, so solution was edited.

Comment: Thanks :) this is exactly what i need :)

Comment: @SourajitRoyChowdhury - You are welcome! Please dont forget accept my solution. Thanks.